# Retrieving values from DB and returning it to calling method

Tags: java, sql-server, database, hashmap

I am retrieving the data from database and want to return it to calling function in the form of Map.

But the issue i am facing here is that the value in form_dtl array gets overrided by the last value.

DB structure is as follows :-

```
base_mainid  form_id               form_link                           form_name

1              1        .//*[@id='collapse-text-dynamic-form-number     WC1
1              2        .//*[@id='collapse-text-dynamic-form-number     WC3
1              3        .//*[@id='collapse-text-dynamic-form-number     WC6
1              4        .//*[@id='collapse-text-dynamic-form-number     WC15
```

How to resolve this ?

```
public static Map formXPath(int formid)
{
    int form_id = -1;
    Statement s3 = null;
    String[] form_dtl = new String[2];
    try {
        s3 = con.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT form_id,form_link,form_name FROM form_details where base_mainid = " + formid;

    ResultSet rs2 = s3.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs2.next()) {

        form_id = rs2.getInt(1);
        form_dtl[0] = rs2.getString(2);
        form_dtl[1] = rs2.getString(3);


    //    System.out.println("ID : "+formid+" Name : "+form_dtl[2]);
        form.put(form_id, form_dtl);

    }
    return form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, instanciate your `form_dtl` array inside the loop so that you have a new one at every iteration. If not, you are always using the same one and the values get overriden.

```
public static Map<Integer, String[]> formXPath(int formid) {
    Map<Integer, String[]> form = new HashMap<>();
    int form_id = -1;
    Statement s3 = null;
    String[] form_dtl;
    try {
        s3 = con.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT form_id,form_link,form_name FROM form_details where base_mainid = " + formid;

        ResultSet rs2 = s3.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs2.next()) {
            // instanciate here
            form_dtl = new String[2];

            form_id = rs2.getInt(1);
            form_dtl[0] = rs2.getString(2);
            form_dtl[1] = rs2.getString(3);
            form.put(form_id, form_dtl);
        } 

    } catch(Exception e) { /* Handle exception here */ }

    return form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are overrided because you are saving the information in the same place for every step in the while loop.

```
while (rs2.next()) {

    form_id = rs2.getInt(1);
    form_dtl[0] = rs2.getString(2);
    form_dtl[1] = rs2.getString(3);

    form.put(form_id, form_dtl);
}
```

Every time you execute the loop (in this case with the DB contents, four times) you are overriden the values in form_dtl.